# Cannot execute SQL HANA query in Python - syntax error

Tags: python, hana

I have problem executing SQL HANA query in Python. I established connection (in R I am able to connect to this HANA data table and it's working perfectly) but in Python I receive syntax error related to query -> I searched multiple sources how to deal with this query `'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM _SYS.TEMP_VALIDATION_09/TEMP_123'` but I did not find answer. In R it looks like this `' SELECT TOP 10 * FROM "_SYS"."TEMP_VALIDATION_09/TEMP_123" '`

```
from hdbcli import dbapi

#Initialize your connection
conn = dbapi.connect(address = '',
              port = , 
              user = '', 
              password = '')
​
print('connected')

cursor = conn.cursor()

query = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM _SYS.TEMP_VALIDATION_09/TEMP_123'
print(query)

result = cursor.execute(query)
for result in cursor:
    print(result)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sap hana - select top expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592876/sap-hana-select-top-expression)

Comment: have you tried to use double quotes around the table name like ```query = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM _SYS."TEMP_VALIDATION_09/TEMP_123"'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find the answer. It's related how identifiers are treated

> There are two types Quotation mark for delimit: Single
>   Quotation Mark (' ') – It is used to delimit the string. Double
>   Quotation Mark (" ") – It is used for delimiting identifiers.

The solution:

```
query = ' SELECT TOP 10 * FROM "_SYS"."TEMP_VALIDATION_09/TEMP_123" '
```